# Is it possible to add a prebuilt APK to an AOSP build as an user app?

Tags: android, makefile, apk, android-source

I am looking to add a prebuilt APK to my AOSP build. I can already do this by doing the following:

1. Add the APK to the *$root_of_my_source_tree/packages/apps* folder.
2. Create an *Android.mk* file. The file has the following contents:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

   LOCAL_MODULE := <name of APK>

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <Name of APK>.apk

   LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS

   LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

   LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

   include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
   ```
3. Add:

   ```
   PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \ <name of APK>
   ```

   To a make file that gets picked up by the AOSP build system.

This adds the APK to the */system/app* folder which is read-only so the user will not be able to update the APK. I would like the APK to be placed in the */data/app* folder so the user can actually update the prebuilt APK.

I have tried the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827/how-do-i-add-apks-in-an-aosp-build) question and they did not work. I tried the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984572/install-an-app-into-data-app-instead-of-system-app-in-the-android-source-compil) question and while it did output the APK to the */data/app* folder of the finished build, once I flashed the image onto my device, the app was not there. The second answer in that question does provide a possible explanation for this but no other suggestions.

Ultimately, I need an APK preloaded in my build that can be updated so if this doesn't work or is a bad approach, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: "once I flashed the image onto my device, the app was not there" -- what does this mean? Do you mean that the file was missing from `/data/app`? Do you mean that the app was in `/data/app` but did not show up in Settings? Do you mean that the app was in `/data/app`, showed up in Settings, but did not show up in the home screen launcher? Do you mean something else?

Comment: 1. When I run my build script for my AOSP image, I get two types of output: a *system.img* file and a bunch of files in 
the *out/target/product/<vendor>/* folder. The files in the folder are usually representative of what will be loaded to the device once the system image has finished flashing. For example, if my app is in the *out/target/product/<vendor>/system/app* folder, I am 99.99% sure that the app will be loaded to the device once the system image is flashed and it will be located under the */system/app* folder.

Comment: 2. My issue is that I need to load my app under */data/app* so it can be deleted or updated as needed. The answer below does generate the app in *out/target/product/<vendor>/data/app/* instead of *out/target/product/<vendor>/system/app/* but once I am done flashing the system image the app is not there.

Comment: "but once I am done flashing the system image the app is not there" -- no offense, but your two comments, in the end, repeat the same passage that I inquired about in my original comment. Please explain, **in precise technical terms**, what "the app is not there" means.

Comment: The APK is missing from *data/app*. The app is not under settings, and it is not in the launcher. With that said, I have found out enough information to answer my own question. I am posting an answer below.

Comment: The AOSP's default behavior is to not pack userdata.img into final build

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249458/pre-installing-android-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the standard behavior of the PackageManager class good enough for my use case. So here are a couple tidbits worth explaining:

- Lavakush's answer does work and it does output the APK to the *out/target/product/vendor/data/app* folder in the source tree but the APK does not show up under */data/app* in the system image once it's flashed onto a device. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984572/) answer, the Android build system does not build anything into */data/* so that explains that. I still find it confusing that it does show up as output in the *out/target/product/vendor/data/app* folder however.
- In my use case, I need to preload APKs onto a build and then update them as needed. Due to the read-only nature of the */system/app* folder I assumed that I would not be able to update my app which is why I wanted to preload it to */data/app*. As in turns out, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825045/) answer & to my testing, the *PackageInstaller* class' standard behavior is to install the updated APK to the *data/app* folder and to start running this APK instead of the preloaded */system/app* APK. The answer also says that the *settings->apps* screen will give you the option to uninstall the updated APK and then you'll be left with the original *system/app* APK. I did observe this behavior and it is fine for my use case.

Comment: Daniel, I also want to install an apk file as a user app so that the user can uninstall.
Can you share more detail?

Answer (score 2):

In your Android.mk file Use LOCAL_MODULE_PATH to TARGET_OUT_DATA or TARGET_OUT_DATA_APPS

```
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)
------
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: Both did produce a system image with the APK in the *data/app* folder but once I flashed the image, the app was not loaded. Do you know why this happened? Or Do you know any other approach to preload an APK as an user app?